# boost::archive::binary_iarchive invalid signature

Tags: c++, boost, computer-vision, boost-serialization

when i use boost::archive::binary_iarchive , the error occur :invalid signature
when i want to compile the program--cvpr_2012_ffd.you can get it from http://blog.gimiatlicho.webfactional.com/?page_id=38. I compile the program according to it's README. when I run this program that I encounter some error.the error is this

```
l00138375@l00138375:/home/hm/downloads/cvpr_2012_public$ ./FaceForest 1      data/config_ffd.txt data/config_headpose.txt data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
Image pathdata/index_random_subset.txt
paths to treesdata/trees_ffd/
Image path 
paths to treesdata/trees_headpose/tree_
10 to load.
Archive Exception during deserializing:
invalid signature
it was tree: data/trees_headpose/tree_000.txt
segment fault
```

I find this error appear in the file:tree.hpp the code like this

```
224     //check if file exist
225     std::ifstream ifs(path.c_str());
226     if (!ifs) {
227       std::cout << "Tree not found " << path << std::endl;
228       return false;
229     }
230 
231     //load tree
232     try {
233 //      boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
234       boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
235       ia >> *t;
236     } catch (boost::archive::archive_exception& ex) {
237       std::cout << "Archive Exception during deserializing:" << std::endl;
238       std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
239       std::cout << "it was tree: " << path << std::endl;
240     } catch (int e) {
241       std::cout << path << "EXCEPTION " << e << std::endl;
242 
243     }
```

the error occur in the line:234

Do somebody encounter this error?how to solve this problem ?thanks

Comment: I compile this program on a linux machine,which os is 64 bit.it can work.i think that tree_000.txt   maybe is 64 bit binary file.I want to   ask how to transform this file to 32bit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of the program you try to compile.
The problem is that the files you try to load are 64 bit linux/mac binaries.

If you are using 32 bit linux or 32/64 windows, than you can't load the files.

Just contact me if you need the 32-bit binary models.